# Excel 2003 Links Paths not including drive

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have an Excel 2003 Spreadsheet which reference other add-ins.
The add-ins are installed in the same location in all PCs at C:\program files\MyPlugins\
Now I moved the spreadsheet to a Network Drive P:

When I try to open the spreadsheet from the P: drive it is giving me an errors that it can't find the add-ins. I looked in the Links and it is now looking at P:\program files\MyPlugins\  and obviously can't find it.

I believe somehow the spreadsheet is using relative paths instead of including the full path and the drive letter.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I have figured out how to do this. Basically I open my Excel spreadsheet on another drive let's say X:. Obviously the links are broken so I manually add a reference to my addin located on C: drive. This makes Excel to use absolute references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue when moving or emailing files.

If its only a few links in one file then you can remap them manually from P:\ to C:\ via Edit - Links

For lots of files a utility is the way to go. You can use Bill Manville's LinkManager, available [here](http://www.manville.org.uk/software/linkmgr.htm) to re-map from your UNC path.

Comment: I have tried using Link Manager on the Excel file on my C: drive and the location Link Manager returns is an absolute path from C: drive. I was expecting to see a relative path so I can change to an absolute one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [something about that problem](http://idevlop.blogspot.com/2009/08/creer-des-references-relatives-ou.html), 2 years ago. It's in French, but the formulae are in English, and you can have it [automatically translated](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http://idevlop.blogspot.com/2009/08/creer-des-references-relatives-ou.html&hl=en&tbb=1&ie=UTF-8) for what it's worth...